# Why this GLSL code don't work on old Intel card (openGL 2.1)?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, intel, vertex-shader

As we know, almost all 3D software has an XYZ-axis in the view section. Suppose to draw a coordinate axis like that. Here is my method.

Firstly, there is a function named **drawOneAxis()** used to draw just one axis. we invoke it three
times. However, everytime before we draw an axis, change the model matrix so that we can get three axes perpendicular to each other. This is what function **changeUniform_MVP()** do.

```
void draw()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)  // 0 - X axis, 1 - Y axis, 2 - Z axis
    {
        changeUniform_MVP(i);
        drawOneAxis();
    }
}
```

Vertex shader:

```
#version 110

uniform mat4 MVP;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = MVP * gl_Vertex;
}
```

In function **init()**, the shader is compiled and linked successfully and we get a program id named *programID*. At the end of **init()**, we use the shader by invoke **glUseProgram(*programID*)**.

The result on my two computers:

```
PC 1: intel card, openGL 3.1, all is well
PC 2: intel card, openGL 2.1, only one axis is drew (Z axis)
```

Why we get two different results here?
One Magic thing!!! The result is correct on PC2 after add two lines of code to function **draw()**.

```
void draw()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        glUseProgram(programID);  // 1
        changeUniform_MVP(i);
        drawOneAxis();
        glUseProgram(0);  // 2
    }
}
```

It seems we must reset the program every time we draw something. But I think it is unnecessary because we use the same shader to draw all the things. I'm very confused about this.

Is it a bug of the old Intel card's driver? Why it is OK after add the two lines of code?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to answer. Older Intel OpenGL drivers do have issues.

drawThreeAxes() perhaps?